# How to monitor the memory usage of the process hosting codedui test (QTAgent)?

Tags: unit-testing, memory-leaks, coded-ui-tests

my codedui test have a memory leak and i want to better identify the source of that leak - do you know a way to monitor the QTAgent process who runs the codedui test?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you need the agent to be running, but the following is [advised by Microsoft](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560134%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to find memory leaks:

Launch performance monitor by typing `perfmon` into `Start > Run`. Click on the performance monitor and the green plus icon.

Add the following counters for your process here:

`Process-->Private Bytes`

`Process-->Virtual Bytes`

To save the log data right click on `Performance Monitor` in the left panel and click on `New > Data Collector Set`. Name and save it somewhere, then in the last step check `Start this data collector set now`.

This will give you a log file for your process.

To read the data use both graphs:

The **Private Bytes** counter indicates the total amount of memory that a process has allocated, not including memory shared with other processes.

The **Virtual Bytes** counter indicates the current size of the virtual address space that the process is using.

After this try using [UMDH](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff560206(v=vs.85).aspx) to find the source of the problem.