# CodedUI OutOf Memory Exception

Tags: automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

I have a long test which I created with the CodedUI testbuilder.

My test run successfully but when test is finished and CodedUI wants to show me whether the test succeeded or failed (red or green), it takes a long time and then it shows me that the test failed. The failure is because of an OutOfMemory exception. So what is the problem? The test itself ran successfully. I'm thinking returning back to VS created this problem.

What is the solution?

Thanks.

Comment: Could you add the complete error given?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29731604/how-to-monitor-the-memory-usage-of-the-process-hosting-codedui-test-qtagent

Comment: r u running the test using a test agent or locally?

Answer (score 0):

Lower the EqtTraceLevel setting in the app config.  Sometimes coded ui will exhaust it's own memory trying to process too many screen shots or other diagnostic data at the end of a test.

```
<system.diagnostics>

    <switches>

      <add name="EqtTraceLevel" value="2" />

    </switches>

  </system.diagnostics>
```